# Continuous Bijection From $S^1$ to $[0,2\pi)$

Tags: general-topology, trigonometry

I came up with the following (I believe) continuous bijection $\theta: S^1  \rightarrow [0,2\pi)$:

$\begin{align} \theta(x,y) & = 
\begin{cases} 
      \arctan(\frac{y}{x}) & x > 0, 0 \leq y < 1 \\
      \frac{\pi}{2} & x = 0, y = 1 \\
      \arctan(\frac{-x}{y}) + \frac{\pi}{2} & x < 0, 0 < y < 1 \\
      \pi & x = -1, y = 0 \\
      \arctan(\frac{-y}{-x}) + \pi & x < 0, -1 < y < 0 \\
      \frac{3\pi}{2} & x = 0, y = -1 \\
      \arctan(\frac{x}{-y}) + \frac{3\pi}{2} & x > 0, -1 < y < 0 \\
\end{cases}
\end{align}$

This looks ugly though. Is there a more natural way to write a continuous bijection from $S^1$ to $[0,2\pi)$?

Comment: yes, there is, take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)

Comment: What is $S^1$..?

Comment: There is no such function (otherwise $S^1$ and $[0,2\pi)$ would be homeomorphic, which they clearly are not by looking at cut-points)

Comment: A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot find such a bijection since the image of a compact set by a continuous function is compact, $S^1$ is compact and $[0,2\pi)$ is not compact.

Comment: What if we define topology on $[0,2\pi)$ by that generated by base of sets of the form $(a,b), 0 \leq a < b \leq 2\pi$ and $[0,a) \cup (b,2\pi), 0 < a < b < 2\pi$

Answer (score 1):

A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism and so no such function can exist. These spaces are clearly not homeomorphic by the cut-point properties of the spaces - $S^1$ has no cut-points, $[0,2\pi)$ has every point except one ($0$) being a cut-point.